# How can I display date information in document class "amsproc"?

Tags: datetime, amsproc

I tried to display the date information by the command `\date{June, 2013}` in document class "amsproc", but failed. How to fix this problem?

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a title}

%    Remove any unused author tags.

%    author one information
\author{Shan Zhang}
\address{Department of Economics, University of Pennsylvania}
\curraddr{Philidelphia, PA}
\email{szhang@upenn.edu}
\thanks{This is thanks 1}

%    author two information
\author{Si Li}
\address{Department of Economics, UToronto}
\curraddr{Toronto}
\email{sili@utoronto.edu}
\thanks{This is thanks 2}

\date{June, 2013}

\dedicatory{To our families}

\begin{abstract}
This is abstract.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

Let's do section 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that `amsproc` doesn't support a date field. Have a look at the documentation to see details. `amsart` sets the date in the footnote. Do you really need `amsproc`?

Comment: I like the format of amsproc, since it has many things I want in the format. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `amsart` class prints the date in the footnote before the thanks. Maybe you could just switch to using the `amsart` class.

Or you can adopt its definition of the respective macro `\@adminfootnotes` for use with `amsproc`. The definitions in `amsproc` and `amsart` differ only in the line concerning the date:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\makeatletter
\def\@adminfootnotes{%
  \let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
  \ifx\@empty\@date\else \@footnotetext{\@setdate}\fi%%   <------ added
  \ifx\@empty\@subjclass\else \@footnotetext{\@setsubjclass}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\@keywords\else \@footnotetext{\@setkeywords}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\thankses\else \@footnotetext{%
    \def\par{\let\par\@par}\@setthanks}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{This is a title}

%    author one information
\author{Shan Zhang}
\address{Department of Economics, University of Pennsylvania}
\curraddr{Philidelphia, PA}
\email{szhang@upenn.edu}
\thanks{This is thanks 1}

%    author two information
\author{Si Li}
\address{Department of Economics, UToronto}
\curraddr{Toronto}
\email{sili@utoronto.edu}
\thanks{This is thanks 2}

\date{June, 2013}

\dedicatory{To our families}

\begin{abstract}
This is abstract.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

Let's do section 1.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on your use case you must redefine `\@maketitle` to include your date somewhere, or use e.g. `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` package to change a part of the macro.

Comment: Your solution is great. I will follow yours.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `amsproc`, page 1:

> The AMS produces three major types of publications: journals (both print and
>   electronic), proceedings volumes, and monographs. There is a core AMS document
>   class for each: amsart, amsproc and amsbook, respectively.

and page 4:

[image]

Since `amsproc` is designed for proceedings volumes, the date field is not needed. Hence, this field is not supported in `amsproc`.

Do you ***REALLY***  need this document class?

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I do want to use amsproc to enjoy some of its features. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @PaulLiu I strongly recommend you not using templates that you are not familiar with. If you like some of `amsproc`'s features, you'd better reproduce them in your own document. Using a document class recklessly, like this, is always not a good choice.